# Are modern conglomerate mergers better or worse for economic competition?

Tags: microeconomics, reference-request, industrial-organisation, competition

Modern conglomerate mergers differ from those from decades ago as, even though they takeover smaller companies, they have a more narrow focus on related business and, in order to be successful, have an extremely rigorous financial control and seek to be as efficient as possible.
Research I've read shows that there's not enough evidence to say that old conglomerate mergers (1980's) distorted or reduced competition, however, I can't find research on modern firms.
Do you have any knowledge on this? If you can link articles it would be great.